# Right G-Space (Husemoller, Fiber Bundles)

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

Hussemoller's definition of a right G-space confuses me at a few key points:

For a topological group G, a right G-space is a space $X$
together with a map $X \times G \xrightarrow{\quad }X$. The image of $(x, s) \in X \times G$ under this map
is $xs$. We assume the following axioms.

(1) For each $x \in X, s,t \in G$, the relation $x(st) = (x s)t$ holds

(2) (Not represented in my diagrams) For each $x \in X$ the relation $x e_G = x$ holds, where $e_G$ is the identity of $G$.

---

I'm not interested or concerned with (2), so we'll ignore it and focus the concern on (1), which confuses me and I want a clarification on. I want to more explicitly label what group operations are happening at each point. Denote the group law for $G$ as $\left( G\times G \xrightarrow{\quad \ddagger \quad } G \right)$ and our other binary operation as $\left( X \times G \xrightarrow{\quad * \quad}G \right)$.

**(I)**

Is this more explicit restatement of (1) correct?

For each $x, (x * s) \in X $ and $s, t \in G$, it holds that $x * (s \ddagger t) = (x * s) \ddagger t$

That is, did Husemoller use concatenation to denote two separate binary operations that are at play? The right side of the equality has a strange implication if true: it must hold that $x * s$ is also in $G$, since the group law is being applied to it.

---

Clearly $X$ and $G$ are topological spaces, with $G$ as a group too.

**(II)**

What of $X \times G$? Does it need to also be a topological space formed from the product topology, or can it simply be a product of the two sets with the binary function $*(X \times G)$ placed on it? No matter what answer you give, please explain and justify the response.

---

As always, thank you greatly for the help.

Comment: (1) is trivially satisfied. You have a typo here. In (2) you should delete the comma after x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I) Yes, both (distinct) binary operations are denoted by concatenation. In case one wants to be explicit about the operations, conventional notation would be something like denoting the multiplication $G\times G\rightarrow G$ by an infix "$\cdot$" and the operation $X\times G\rightarrow X$ by an infix "$.$". The correct statement of axiom (1) then becomes that $x.(s\cdot t)=(x.s).t$ for $x\in X$ and $s,t\in G$.

(II) The space $X\times G$ is equipped with the product topology. This is general topological convention: If the product of two topological spaces is introduced, it is always assumed to be equipped with the product topology unless explicitly stated otherwise. The operation is given by a map $X\times G\rightarrow X$, i.e. continuous with respect to this topology.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark it as the answer if you can just answer the last part of **(I)**: Is it mandatory then that (in your notation) $(x . s) \in G$? It would have to be from the right-hand-side of the equality, because that's where the group law "lives".  It would be strange then, because that would imply that the operation also goes into codomain $G$ as well as $X$.

Also, Do you have a typo? I think you want to write in the last line of paragraph 1 that: "axiom (1) then becomes that $x . (s \cdot t) = (x . s) \cdot t$ for $x \in X$"

Comment: Although it may not be a typo. Definitely thinking about it.

Comment: No, it is not a typo (what I'm saying here is not the same as what you give in your post; that is the crux). The operation is a map $X\times G\rightarrow X$, so, given $x\in X$ and $s\in G$, we have $x.s\in X$. Then, $(x.s).t$ makes sense because $x.s\in X$ and $t\in G$. For $(x.s)\cdot t$ to make sense, it would indeed be necessary to have $x.s\in G$, but that is *not* what the definition demands.